# When can I do more voyages

Tags: godus

When I try to do a voyage I see the following text.

> Voyage Complete - More Voyages coming soon!

I've seen this text for 3 days now. When will I be able to go on a journey again? 
I've only done one journey so far. Good old mr. Google told be I should be able to do this once a day but I'm not.

I'm playing on Android.
Did I run into a bug or what is needed so I can journey again?

Comment: on iPad, same thing for 2days.

Answer (score 2):

No, the game did not bug for you. That means you've completed all currently available levels for the Voyages. You'll have to wait until 22Cans releases new Voyages levels until you can play Voyages again.

Comment: Not correct. Only did 1 Voyage, a friend of mine, with less progress, did plenty more.

Comment: If that's the case, then the game may have bugged on you. You can try restarting your game's progress to force Voyages to open again, but even then it's not worth it. Currently, there are only about five Voyages missions playable.